# Adding JPA Non primary key referenced ManyToOne entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
public class DemandItem extends BaseEntity{
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {})
    @JoinColumn(name = "sku_code",referencedColumnName = "sku_code", nullable = false)
    private Inventory inventory;

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(Inventory inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public void setSkuCode(String skuCode){
        if(this.inventory == null){
            this.setInventory(new Inventory(skuCode));
        }
    }

    public String getSkuCode(){
        if(this.inventory != null){
            return this.inventory.getSkuCode();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Now for creating a DemandItem I should first Load the inventory using skuCode and then set the inventory using setInventory. Just calling setSkuCode function causing transient entity exception. How to solve it,

1. I need to just get the skuCode filled while creating the data, but i dont need to load it while creating this entity.
2. While fetching I need the Inventory entity to be loaded.

Comment: @ManyToOne's fetch is by default `eager` so you inventory will be loaded when the DemandItem  is fetched.
setting inventory should be in a persistence context, it shouldn't be new cause your Orm won't be able to identify it on the db.

Comment: While persisting you will have to set the associated `Inventory` on the `DemandItem` before persisting the `DemandItem`.

Comment: You can fetch the inventory in one line of code. I'm not sure exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why do I load the DB data for every saving of DemandItem record ?....I am just storing only sku code in the DemandItem record...And I only need to get the inventory while a fetch of DemandItem happens..For me read is less and wirte of DemandItems are frequent...There is no use of of loading the Inventory always for every write of DemandItem